# I am getting a rust compile error with lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to get some rust code to compile, but I keep getting errors about types and lifetimes. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

I am getting an error in the compile: `associated type bindings must be declared after generic parameters`. I have tried, I think, all combinations of parameters and none of them seem to work.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```rust
/*! test of lifetimes for compile */
extern crate web_view;
use web_view::*;
struct UserData {}

type TestResult = WVResult<i64>;
type TestView = WebView<UserData>;
type TestBuilder<'a> = WebViewBuilder< UserData: 'a,'a, 
         FnMut(&mut TestView, &str) -> TestResult, String>; // compile error

fn main() {
    let mut p = UserData {};
    let wvb: TestBuilder = WebViewBuilder::new();
    let mut webview: TestView = wvb
        .title("Progress")
        .content("hello")
        .size(640, 960)
        .resizable(true)
        .debug(false)
        .user_data(p)
        .invoke_handler(handler)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let _res = webview.run().unwrap();
}
fn handler(webview: &mut TestView, arg: &str) -> TestResult {
    Ok(1)
}
```

*This should be a comment, but it is too long to fit in a comment. I've used @zizka's answer, but restored my original version of TestResult. Now I am getting errors that "function or associated item not found" and "no method named `title` found for type"*

```rust
use web_view::*;

struct UserData {}

type TestResult = WVResult<i64>;
type TestView<'a> = WebView<'a, UserData>;
type TestBuilder<'a> =
    WebViewBuilder<'a, UserData, fn(&mut TestView, &str) -> TestResult, &'static str>;

fn main() {
    let p = UserData {};

    let builder: TestBuilder = TestBuilder::new(); // error here
    let webview = builder
        .title("Progress") // error here
        .content(Content::Url("https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"))
        .size(640, 960)
        .resizable(true)
        .debug(false)
        .user_data(p)
        .invoke_handler(handler)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    webview.run().unwrap();
}

fn handler(_webview: &mut TestView, _arg: &str) -> TestResult {
    Ok(17 as i64)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues

#### `TestView`

Your definition:

```rust
type TestView = WebView<UserData>;
```

`WebView` is defined as:

```rust
pub struct WebView<'a, T: 'a> {
    inner: *mut CWebView,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a mut T>,
}
```

It expects lifetime and `T`, which must live as long as the lifetime. Fixed definition:

```rust
type TestView<'a> = WebView<'a, UserData>;
```

#### `TestBuilder`

Your definition:

```rust
type TestBuilder<'a> = WebViewBuilder< UserData: 'a,'a, 
         FnMut(&mut TestView, &str) -> TestResult, String>;
```

`WebViewBuilder` is defined as:

```rust
pub struct WebViewBuilder<'a, T: 'a, I, C>
    pub title: &'a str,
    pub content: Option<Content<C>>,
    pub width: i32,
    pub height: i32,
    pub resizable: bool,
    pub debug: bool,
    pub invoke_handler: Option<I>,
    pub user_data: Option<T>,
}
```

- `'a` lifetime must be first, you have it after `UserData`
- `UserData` expects lifetime -> `UserData<'a>`, not `UserData: 'a`
- `FnMut(...)` is a trait, which means that the size is not known at compile time, you have to wrap it with `Box`, use `fn`, ...
- `C` is a `String` in your case, which means that you can't use `.content("hello")`, because a) it expects `Content<C>`, b) even if you use `Content::Html("hello")` it won't work, because it's `Content<&'static str>` and you said that you want `Content<String>` -> `Content::Html("hello".to_string())`

Fixed definition:

```rust
type TestBuilder<'a> =
    WebViewBuilder<'a, UserData, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut TestView, &str) -> TestResult>, String>;
```

#### `WebViewBuilder`

But even if you fix all these things, it won't work. Look at the `WebViewBuilder` implementations:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a, I, C> Default for WebViewBuilder<'a, T, I, C>
where
    I: FnMut(&mut WebView<T>, &str) -> WVResult + 'a,
    C: AsRef<str>
{...}
```

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a, I, C> WebViewBuilder<'a, T, I, C>
where
    I: FnMut(&mut WebView<T>, &str) -> WVResult + 'a,
    C: AsRef<str>,
{...}
```

Especially this line:

```rust
I: FnMut(&mut WebView<T>, &str) -> WVResult + 'a
```

It expects `WVResult` (-> `Result<(), Error>`), which means that you can't use your `TestResult` (-> `WVResult<i64>` -> `Result<i64, Error>`). There're no other implementations in the source code.

### An example

Working code, which does use your types, but the `TestResult` is just `WVResult` (`i64` -> `()`).

```rust
use web_view::*;

struct UserData {}

type TestResult = WVResult;

type TestView<'a> = WebView<'a, UserData>;

type TestBuilder<'a> =
    WebViewBuilder<'a, UserData, Box<dyn FnMut(&mut TestView, &str) -> TestResult>, String>;

fn main() {
    let p = UserData {};

    let wvb: TestBuilder = WebViewBuilder::new();
    let webview: TestView = wvb
        .title("Progress")
        .content(Content::Url(
            "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page".to_string(),
        ))
        .size(640, 960)
        .resizable(true)
        .debug(false)
        .user_data(p)
        .invoke_handler(Box::new(handler))
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let _res = webview.run().unwrap();
}

fn handler(_webview: &mut TestView, _arg: &str) -> TestResult {
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: _Which means that the result is either `()` or an `Error`_ No: it means that the result is either `T` or an `Error`, and that the default is `T = ()` if not specified. The OP is specifying that `T = i64`, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ooops, don't answer in the morning. Going to fix it.

Comment: @Jmb thanks, fixed. Did update the answer and I also found that it's impossible to use `WVResult<i64>`. `()` must be used, because of the `where` constraints like `I: FnMut(&mut WebView<T>, &str) -> WVResult + 'a`.

Comment: I have added a new version on the end of the original post as it did not fit in a comment. Presumably, there is some issue with visibility in derived types.... Maybe I need to raise an issue against the crate.

Comment: .... Maybe I should change my strategy to use `WebView().user_data_mut()` for passing data (back) into the `WebView` instead of a return value from the invoke handler.

Comment: It's not about visibility. The implementation says `I: FnMut(&mut WebView<T>, &str) -> WVResult + 'a`. It means that your handler must return `WVResult`, not `WVResult<i64>`. I'd recommend to look at [examples](https://github.com/Boscop/web-view/tree/master/examples).

Comment: It seems that the user_data is not visible from the JavaScript, so that won't work either... The go version has some code to Bind a Go object to the JavaScript, but that does not appear to be visible from C++ or Rust. Sorry, I seem to be getting off my original topic. I need to pursue this on a web_view issue somewhere.